# AuthenticationTicket byte[] value cannot deserialize when server restart

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Im currently using ITicketStore to implement a PersistentTicketStore to store user session in Database. This is the Ticket that use to store in Db:

```
public class Ticket
{
   public string Id { get; set; }

   public string UserId { get; set; }

   public byte[] Value { get; set; } 

   public DateTimeOffset? LastActivity { get; set; }

   public DateTimeOffset? Expires { get; set; }
}
```

The class **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationTicket** will be serialize to byte[]  and store in **Value** field. When User visit the site, the server will deserialize form byte back to **AuthenticationTicket** to validate user session. When the server is running it works no problem, but whenever I restart server it can't deserialize the **Value** anymore. So the authentication fails and the user has an invalid login.

**UPDATE**

When debugging, I discovered that, when I first store and query the Value, its length is 902, but when I restart the server, I query the Value and its length becomes double 1804, though even though I checked the Value field in the Db, it was the same before and after I restarted the server. Still don't know why this happened... I'm using Postgresql.

Comment: After you restart the server, the stored byte[] is 1804, which does not match the one in the database?

Comment: @Chaodeng After I restart the server, I query again and its length is 1804, before restart it is 902. But when I check in the pgadmin page, the value is the same before and after I restart.